# Recursive Definition for Language

Tags: recursion, computer-science, computer-science-theory

Suppose I have a language consisting of just balanced parentheses, i.e., {ε, ( ), ( ( ) ), ( ) ( ), ( ( ( ) ) ), ( ( ) ( ) ), ... } and I'm asked to write a recursive definition for it. Could somebody give me an example of what that could look like? - I'm a bit new to this type of computer science theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A kind of recursive definition is  grammar.  To generate language of balanced parentheses :

```
S --> (S) | SS | ^
```

this is recursive because `S` appears in `RHS` of production rules.

production rules:   `LHS --> RHS`

**EDIT**

Why `(s)` not `S` ?

because to add `()` pairs recursively and more then one time.

```
S --> (S) --->  ((S))
```

in second step inner `S` is replaced by `(S)`.

Comment: Could you please explain this a bit more?: why (S) and not S? Also, why stop at SS - why not SSSS as well?

Comment: @JohnRoberts to get SSSS you apply the rule twice: S->SS->SSSS.

Comment: @JohnRoberts  `^` is used to convert sentential form into sentence. `S--^` can you `use S --> (S) ---> ((S)) --^ --> (())`

Answer (score -2):

```
TEXT ::= BRACES | BRACKETS | LIST;
BRACES ::= "{" ( TEXT | /* nothing */ ) "}";
BRACKETS ::= "(" ( TEXT | /* nothing */ ) ")";
LIST ::= ( BRACES | BRACKETS ) | ( BRACES | BRACKETS ) "," LIST;
```

Comment: There are no brackets in the language.